# React native zIndex causes unstable rendering in screen in android

Tags: android, react-native, styles, z-index

have anyone face unstable rendering components in a screen caused by zIndex? i have a screen with multiple components and two components using zIndex is loading and list suggestion. Everytime a put zIndex into those components' container, it causes unstable rendering for components in screen such as: one of components disappear, text images of component disappear just white background, sometime it freeze the screen. I tried some solutions but not solved so I need some advice about this.

My environment

react: ^16.0.0-alpha.6

react-native": ^0.43.4

Genymotion: 2.9.0

Virtual Device: Google Nexus 5X 1080x1920

I posted my code in gist https://gist.github.com/nhuthuynh/009dee73675c1dbed41d34a86b359057

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the above image where is your list suggestion? can you please explain a bit more..

Comment: Are you using the `elevation` style property in any of these views?

Comment: @MotiAzu i tried elevation: 1 or 100, but still not work

Comment: I meant are you using elevation in your solution generally. It's not a solution, but it could be the problem sometimes since it overrides the zIndex.

Comment: And please include a relevant portion of your code here

Comment: @MotiAzu i add my code in gist : https://gist.github.com/nhuthuynh/009dee73675c1dbed41d34a86b359057

Comment: it's easy to read all of the code from gist. It's better to provide small part of it, which has problem in here or at least add your project to a project not just a gist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`elevation`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style) in android version of react-native.

Comment: Did you removed zIndex?

Comment: no, i did not remove zIndex. Do i need to remove it ?

Comment: Yes, remove zIndex, and add elevation